# regex remove all non alphanumeric except @

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I remove all non-alphanumeric characters except for @?

```
`@some random text goes here %#KG§ blah`.replace(/\W/g, ``) // replaces all non-alphanumeric but need to keep the @
```

Comment: `.replace(/[^@\w]/g, '')`?

Comment: Thanks Kosh... and if I wanted to also say "except for @ and -" ?

Comment: Y u no read on regex first? =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/[^a-z0-9@]*/g` should work for your case.

```js
console.log(`@some random text goes here %#KG§ blah`.replace(/[^a-z0-9@]*/g, ``))
```

Quick explaniation
We're picking anything that is alphanumeric or '@' and picking any number of them using '*', then the '^' acts as a not.

I often use this site to test my regexp https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use a negated character class that lists `@` and word chars `\w`:

```js
console.log('@some random text goes here %#KG§ blah'.replace(/[^@\w]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'I contains invalid char #@_&';

str.replace((/[^@a-z0-9]+/gi), '');
```

**Please Note that some answers here won't replace something like underscores** `_`

E.g

```
str.replace(/[^@\w]/g, ''))
```

**Because** `\w` matches **underscores**